# highcharts 2 variable JSON (Date, Value) not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Spent over an hour looking at tutorials on highcharts, as well on the posts on here, I can not get the data linking in.  I have a really simple MYSQL request to get a date, and value, looks like this:

> "userChart":[{"eDate":"2015-02-03","usLevel":"2"},{"eDate":"2015-03-11","usLevel":"5"},{"eDate":"2015-03-25","usLevel":"8"}]

This is the code I am using, based on another post on here:

```
      var chart;

    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: []
    }

    // and create the chart
    // chart 1
    options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
    options.title.text = 'Historical Data';
    options.yAxis.title.text = 'Stage';


    // push the data to the series
    $.each(data, function(key, va) {
        options.xAxis.categories = va[0];
        options.series.push(parseFloat(va[1]));
    })


    // create the first chart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

This is the output:
[image]

I am so confused, this is meant to be so simple, yet something i just do not understand.  If someone can point me where I am going wrong, i would be extremely grateful.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
console.log(data)
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the content of data? `console.log(data)` and show the result please

Comment: @R3tep Added an email from console to show the data.  Thank you for looking at this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an error when you use this piece of code

```
$.each(data, function(key, va) {
    options.xAxis.categories = va[0];
    options.series.push(parseFloat(va[1]));
})
```

I think `va` is an object and not an array in your exemple.

Try to use `va` as an object:

```
var dataSeries = {data: []};
data.forEach(function (va) {
    options.xAxis.categories.push(va.eDate);
    dataSeries.data.push(parseFloat(va.usLevel));
})
// And assign the correct format to highcharts series
options.series.push(dataSeries);
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9xdtpnw/1/)

Comment: I did try that, but the data is still empty.  I was hoping for the eDate about the bottom, and a line plotting each usLevel?

Comment: Some mistake in my last code sorry. I don't know if is the better way but it's working... But your major error is the utilisation of va like an array and not an object

Comment: Perfect.  Seems I was getting very confused, especially when looking at other examples.  But thank you very much R3tep.

Comment: @AndrewWalker I updated my exemple with a most elegants code. Good day